# ClickOnce roll back on failed migration

Tags: c#, clickonce, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations, fluent-migrator

I have been using clickonce approach to deploy and update my point of sale system. Now I want to add database migrations to it. For that, I will be using FluentMigrator. The problem now occurs is that if the migration fails I don't want to update the application as it will have crashes. So the question is

1. Is there a way to run migration commands first and then ask the user to update the app?
2. Is there a way to roll back installation if the migration fails?

Comment: It is the nature of ClickOnce that _software update_ can occur before your application even runs so am not sure how you can perform a DB rollback

Comment: @MickyD so what do you suggest?